# Principal components analysis missing data SPSS

Tags: pca, spss, missing-data

I have a large data set (27k) There are 63 variables of interest. I attempted PCA as a dimensionality reduction strategy. The items are scored on different metrics ranging from dichotomous variables to variables with 7 response selections. There is also a lot missing data. When I try to run PCA (in SPSS) I get an error message. I have tried standardizing the scores and listwise and pairwise deletion of missing cases but still get the error message. What am I doing wrong? Please advise. Thank you

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Most importantly, *why* are these data missing?  What you can do about it depends on that.

Comment: Not sure why data are missing. Data was collected in 2021 by a national organization

Comment: The error message (Warning) states that there are fewer than two cases, at least one of the variables has zero variance, there is only one variable in the analysis, or correlation coefficients could not be computed for all pairs of variables. No further statistics will be computed.

Comment: Have you looked at the variables' means, sds, ranges and distributions? Sounds like something is off in the raw data so you probably have to do some manual data inspection, it's impossible to say what it is without seeing the data. In SPSS, variable measure type can also sometimes affect functions (some analysis assuming scale variables won't run if any variables are specified as nominal and vice versa).